# Is there an equivalent of ngCsp for Angluar2?

Tags: angular, angularjs-service, angular2-directives

Is there an equivalent of **ngCsp** for **Angluar2**?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is implemented yet

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6361
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1744

This comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1744#issuecomment-168540571 seems to indicate that the offline template compiler that will be shipped soon will fix this.